# Danksharding questions

Tags: sharding, networking, danksharding, eip-4844

After reading so many articles, still feel like several gaps in my understanding. Posting my current understanding/questions, appreciate any insights, corrections.

1. At the blob source (e.g) say the L2 operator has 128K worth of data to post to L1 (4K elements, each 32 bytes)

- The blob is erasure coded, resulting in 256K (8K elements)
- Polynomial for these points is computed, KZG commitment is derived
- The KZG commitment is published in a "blob transaction" to L1

2. On the L1 side:

- The consensus nodes are partitioned into shards. Let us say 64 shards. So the blob in question has 64 X 4K parts
- Nodes in each shard download the 4K worth of data assigned to their shard, verify it against the KZG commitment

3. Block proposer

- One of the L1 nodes proposes the block, sticks in the KZG commitment in the block. At this point, it already downloaded the portion assigned to its shard and verified it

4. Block verifier

- It is not clear how the verifier checks if the data has been seen by all the shards? Does it randomly pick a node from each shard and ask if they have seen the data assigned to their shard? Or probably something else ..

5. L2 fraud proof generation

- The full blob needs to be available in order to verify the L2 post state hash. Does the verifier pick a node at random from each shard and download their portion, combine them to build the full blob? Or probably something else ..

Also not clear how the proposer/builder separation, DAS fit in here

Thanks